# Is there a solution on the error: Error in file(file, "rt" : cannot open the connection

Tags: r, error-handling

I'm trying to run the following code in the package 'activPAL':

```
activity.summary.by.window.duration(location_file, output_folder, window_duration = 2)
```

specifically:

```
activity.summary.by.window.duration("/Users/Femke/Documents/FW/Jaar 2/Afstuderen/ActivPAL/14-03/Events.extended", 
                                    "/Users/Femke/Documents/FW/Jaar 2/Afstuderen/ActivPAL/14-03/Output.27-03", 
                                    24)
```

It gives the error:

```
Error in file(file, "rt") : cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning message:
In file(file, "rt") :
  cannot open file '/Users/Femke/Documents/FW/Jaar 2/Afstuderen/ActivPAL/14-03/Events.extendedNA': No such file or directory
```

I checked the filepath with

```
file.exists("/Users/Femke/Documents/FW/Jaar 2/Afstuderen/ActivPAL/14-03/Events.extended")
```

It returned: TRUE, for both folders.

I also tried

```
list.files("/Users/Femke/Documents/FW/Jaar 2/Afstuderen/ActivPAL/14-03/Events.extended")
```

And it gave me the right list of csv files I want to include in the code.

Besides, I have checked:

1. read& write permissions for the folder and files,
2. the right extension (.csv),
3. it is not open in another program,
4. the name is copied and checked for typo's,
5. used setwd("/Users/Femke/Documents/FW/Jaar 2/Afstuderen/ActivPAL/14-03")

Does anybody have ideas how to solve this issue? The goal is to include a folder with csv files in the code. Thank you in advance!

Comment: The warning message states that the file name is `Events.extendedNA`, not `Events.extended`. Where is the NA coming from?

Comment: I am not sure. Here is the input: 
`activity.summary.by.window.duration("/Users/Femke/Documents/FW/Jaar 2/Afstuderen/ActivPAL/14-03/Events.extended", "/Users/Femke/Documents/FW/Jaar 2/Afstuderen/ActivPAL/14-03/Output.27-03")`


The NA appears in the output:
`Error in file(file, "rt") : cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning message:
In file(file, "rt") :
  cannot open file '/Users/Femke/Documents/FW/Jaar 2/Afstuderen/ActivPAL/14-03/Events.extendedNA': No such file or directory`